# How do I use templating properly? I'm having a data type issue with a template<>

Tags: c++, types, prototype, compiler-errors

**EDIT 11/3/2011 9:37pm:**

This is my error:

```
 error: no matching function for call to "charList_join(const char [1], CISP430_A5::linked_list<char>&)"
```

and this is my prototype:

```
template <typename Item>
string charList_join(const char* glue, linked_list<char> pieces);
```

and this is my function call:

```
charList_join("", usedChars)
```

where usedChars is a `static linked_list<char>` declared in the same scope where `charList_join()` is called.

**EDIT 11/4/2011 8:45am:** Ok, so here is my code with unnecessary functions removed:

<sup><sub>[**sehe: edited from pastebin to github**]</sub></sup>

- browse it [online at github](https://gist.github.com/1340832)
- download it with git:

  ```
   git clone git://gist.github.com/1340832.git
  ```

I'm getting the error on line 57, column 68 of premute_append.cpp. I've included the makefile so you can attempt to build it if you want. I'm only getting one single error at this point, but I just don't have any idea what it means.

If you try to compile the error will look like this:

```
[cisw320b_stu022@scc-bdiv-cis assn5]$ make
g++ -c main.cpp
g++ -c permute_append.cpp
permute_append.cpp: In member function âCISP430_A5::linked_list<std::basic_string<char> > CISP430_A5::permute_append::permute(CISP430_A5::linked_list<char>)â:
permute_append.cpp:57:68: error: no matching function for call to âcharList_join(const char [1], CISP430_A5::linked_list<char>&)â
make: *** [permute_append.o] Error 1
```

Any idea why I'm getting this error?

Comment: Post a [sscce](http://sscce.org). This error is most likely being caused by the implementation of `linked_list`, but it difficult to find the cause of this without a complete program that reproduces the error.

Comment: Does changing the prototype to: `string charList_join(const char* glue, CISP430_A5::linked_list<char> pieces);` fix the problem?

Comment: @Mankarse I tried it, but that didn't work.

Comment: Hey, I tried that too but the error identical.

Comment: Hmmm... Its kind of hard to provide a sscce because the actual code is kind of long.

Comment: It may be "kind of hard to provide a sscce", but it's *even harder* for us to answer a question with this much information. How is `linked_list` defined? What else is in `namespace` (/ `class` / `struct`) `CISP430_A5`?

Comment: Alright, let me see if I can post something better today when I work on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string charList_join(const char* glue, linked_list<char> pieces);
```

is actually

```
template< typename Item >
string charList_join(const char* glue, linked_list<char> pieces);
```

Since `Item` is not detected from any of the arguments, you should pass it explicitly:

```
charList_join<SomeItemType>( "", usedChars);
```

Or perhaps you just wanted instead:

```
template< typename Item >
string charList_join(const char* glue, linked_list<Item> pieces);
```

Comment: Indeed using `charList_join<SomeItemType>( "", usedChars);` made he error go away! I guess I need to read up on templates more. So `charList_join<someType>` sets the type for `Item`? Does that mean all uses of `Item` must be limited so `someType` now?

Comment: @trusktr: It sets the type of `Item` within the function, not in the enclosing `class`. Seems most if not all the template functions should instead be just regular functions. Keep the research on templates!

Comment: Thank you! So i learnt that the template prefix is not necessary if the the data types are not ambiguous!

Comment: Also, Johnsyweb mentioned in his answer that I can just omit the template<> prefix altogether.

Comment: @trusktr: Yes, most if not all of them look like an artificial ripple from not understanding templates properly. A member function of a class template does not need to include the `template<>` prefix since its already implicit by its class type, it only needs to do so if its indeed intended to work on a family of types itself.

Comment: Hmmmm.... I don't quite understand what you just wrote. Can you give examples of where I don't need the template prefix in my code?

Comment: @trusktr: Look for a simple tutorial on say lists using templates, and you'll understand how its supposed to be done. There are lots of examples out there. There is also the standard library implementation, but is usually too hard to read due to standard constrains.

Answer (score 2):

You said:

> and this is my prototype:

```
string charList_join(const char* glue, linked_list<char> pieces);
```

But it is not. According to [the code you provided](http://pastie.org/2810555), your declaration is:

```
template <typename Item>
string charList_join(const char* glue, linked_list<char> pieces);
```

Which means that you need to call it like so:

```
charList_join<char>("", usedChars)
```

However, you don't actually use `Item` within this function, so you should just remove the `template` specifier (from the declaration and the definition) and call it as you were. Better still, pass the list *by const-reference*:

```
string charList_join(const char* glue, const linked_list<char>& pieces);
```

The call remains:

```
charList_join("", usedChars)
```

Comment: Oops, it was a typo. I meant to put a return type.

Comment: You did. Now that it bears no resemblance to the one you asked, I can  delete this answer.

Comment: You updated again. Now I can answer, having trawled through lots of unnecessary code.

Comment: Thank you! You and K-ballo both answered with the same answer but he answered first, so I gave it to him. Thank you thank you thank you!