# What does the "(.text+0x0)" in "permute_append.cpp:(.text+0x0)" mean for this C++ error?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I have this error:

```
permute_append.o: In function `CISP430_A5::charList_join(char const*, CISP430_A5::linked_list<char>)':
permute_append.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `CISP430_A5::charList_join(char const*, CISP430_A5::linked_list<char>)'
main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x0): first defined here
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [main] Error 1
```

What does the `(.text+0x0)` mean? I'm used to seeing line:column numbers (e.g. 57:68), but I have no idea what the `(.text+0x0)` means.

Here's the code: https://gist.github.com/1340872/e25ec2aaac99c4005f4b33e6236750a2a6f1791f

Comment: The code you pasted took me 5 minutes _again_ to copy from the paste bin (zip it, already? use github for sharing multiple source files). It was identical to the letter to the code you posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004824/how-do-i-use-templating-properly-im-having-a-data-type-issue-with-a-template). It isn't surprising that error produced is the same as with that OTHER question (`no matching function for call to ‘charList_join`). Is this question obsolete?

Comment: I didn't say the errors are related! It is **not** the same error, so the code posted in the paste bin is not helpful for this question.

Comment: I have compared the versions: there were only whitespace differences (and `makefile` instead of `Makefile`). Unsurprisingly the error is still the same `no matching function for call` instead of `multiple definition of`

Comment: Yeah sorry, I copied over from the paste bins, then forgot to update. The question now contains the link to the updated revision. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means the error was reported during linking, not compiling.

The link error is reported at the very start of the object module (my guess is before it emitted the first data into the .text segment).

In short: it's immaterial here, but other linker errors my have a reference to e.g. the place where an unresolved external was used. Multiple definitions obviously occur in more than one location, which is apparently why the linker can't decide what location to report.

**Hint** 99% of the time this happens when non-generic non-instance methods (in this case, `CISP430_A5::charList_join`) are defined in header files instead of in cpp files. Is that method a static method?

**Edit** Indeed the problem was that the method was defined **inside the header**. Line 201 of linked_list.h **includes** linked_list.template, meaning all definitions from linked_list.template are included. Effectively, that is the same as having the definition *inside* the header file directly.

Now, because

- `linked_list.h` is included in both `main.cpp` and `permute_append.cpp`
- both `main.o` and `permute_append.o` are being linked into the `main` executable

you'll end up with two, conflicting definitions of the global free function `charList_join`. I fixed things and uploaded to [my gist](https://gist.github.com/1340832)

Comment: Hmmm... Well the prototypes are defined in the header files, but the actual function definitions are defined in .cpp or .template files. I updated my question above with links to my code.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I only defined charList_join one time only.

Comment: @trusktr: well, the linker is sure you defined it more than once. I'd trust the linker.

Comment: lol I'm absolutely POSITIVE I didn't define the function twice! You can see one call to the function in permute_append.cpp, the prototype in linked_list.h, and the definition in linked_list.template. There are absolutely no other occurences of "charList_join" in any of the other files.

Comment: @trusktr: you have two options, find the bug in your code/make process or find the bug in the linker :). Right now, I'm not so sure you can even reproduce the error from this question? If so, can you an [edited gist](https://gist.github.com/1340832)?

Comment: Have published a fixed version at [my gist](https://gist.github.com/1340832). The problem arose because you made a templated method non-templated; I fixed it by marking the method `static` (you could in fact have moved the definition from the `.template` file to one of the `.cpp` files instead). HTH

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4736/discussion-between-sehe-and-trusktr)

Comment: @trusktr: I posted a bit of explanation in the chat. I also posted two alternative solutions to the link problem so you understand the options, and _why they work_ in [the original gist](https://gist.github.com/1340832/8e41bf55e87e352da0e779d74b52f0d84c000e62) and [the best-practice (separate compilation unit for linked_list externally linked definitions) solution here](https://gist.github.com/1341449/3cdf0ea9f667500ed0e309be66013d74ceda92ca)

Comment: THanks! As soon as I get back to finishing this assignment, I'll be back here to check it out.

Answer (score 3):

`.text` is the segment (in an object, library or executable file or in memory) that contains executable instructions. In `.text+0x0` the `0x0` is just an offset. Hence the entire `permute_append.cpp:(.text+0x0)` means the beginning (i.e. byte 0x0) of the text segment in the object file created by compiling permute_append.cpp.

Since this is a linkage error, what really matters for you is the symbol name that is given, i.e. `CISP430_A5::charList_join(char const*, CISP430_A5::linked_list<char>)`.